# How to set configuration of NSManagedObjectModel while creating Entites programatically.

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm creating entities in core data's managed object model programmatically using SWIFT.

When I create an array of NSEntityDescription and pass it to

let managedObjectModel : NSManagedObjectModel = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Nequore").managedObjectModel

managedObjectModel.setEntities(arrEntities, forConfigurationName:"Default")

I'm facing crash related to model's configuration which states that

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Entities for a configuration must already be in the model.'

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this crash is explained in [Apple documentation for NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel).  Read the paragraph *Editing Models Programmatically*.

Your statement `let managedObjectModel` is creating a persistent container (Core Data Stack), including a managed object model, which is probably empty (has no entities), and I'm guessing that creating the persistent container is *using* the model in such a way that, per that documentation, it should no longer be edited.  Try to create your managed object model *first*, complete with all entities, and *then* pass that model to `NSPersistentContainer init(name:managedObjectModel:)`.